# Delphi Day/Week Planner

Tags: delphi, scheduling

We are currently looking to develop an application to enable a manager to view and/or modify an employee shift schedule. Shifts cover a 7 day period and do not vary, ie. an employee is always scheduled to follow the same shift pattern.

I've had a look at **TMS DB Planner**, but I would like to compare that against any other VCL components.

Comment: Thank you for all the answers, but at the moment TMS DBPlanner seems to fit better with what we need than the others.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pieter, you ca check the [`ExpressScheduler`](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/VCL/ExScheduler/) component from DevExpress.

Comment: I have the DevEx VCL subscription since years and I really like that library a lot. The learning curve is admittedly steep but you get rewarded with excellent components

Answer (score 1):

Check [EzPlan-IT](http://www.a-dato.net/Products/EzPlanIT/tabid/80/Default.aspx). I haven't tried it yet, but it looks like a feature-rich component.

I tried ExpressScheduler but I think it's too complex for even the simplest uses.

I'm not sure, but I think [JVCL](http://jvcl.delphi-jedi.org/) also has something simillar.

IMO, sometimes it takes less time and effort to make your own component with exact feature set you require than use ready-made ones, since it can take longer to put them to good use.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at TurboPower's open source [Visual PlanIt](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tpvplanit).